# How to simulate an error 500 in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I created an `error500.php` file in `web/errors/` and would now like to test it.

I tried to put this line in one of my actions:

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(500);
```

Unfortunately it looks like it's ignored.

Do you guys have any idea of what's happening here?

I'm using Symfony 1.4.

**Edit:** Firebug is telling me that the error is actually fired but the page is still loading afterwards. And I'm in the prod env.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure throwing any exception should trigger the error page:

```
throw new sfException('Testing the 500 error');
```

However, the location of the error page is different in symfony 1.2+:

```
config/error/error.html.php
```

move your `web/errors/error500.php` file to this location instead.

Comment: Also, you can't test this in dev/test mode. Make sure you are in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll find this site useful http://symfony-check.org/. The second task is about Error 500 page.