# How to Simulate 500 Error in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am wondering how would I simulate a 500 error in Symfony 2.

I have been reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584048/1179449) where **Raise** suggests throwing an exception

> throw new sfException('Testing the 500 error');

in Symfony 1.4.

I have been placing this code in my

```
\store\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.php
```

but I get the fatal error

> Class 'Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\sfException' not found in /home/notroot/www/store/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php on line 49`

Line 49 refers to the exception code I added.

My question is if throwing an exception is still viable in forcing a 500 error in Symfony 2, and if so where do I put this exception?

If this is no longer viable, how would I be able to test for an error 500?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
//in your controller
$response = new Response();
$response->setStatusCode(500);
return $response;
```

Dont forget to add

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

at the top of your file.

**Edit :** To force Symfony 500 error, your proposition is fine :

```
throw new \Exception('Something went wrong!');
```

Put it in a controller function.

Comment: I have placed the `$response` code inside the controller, and inside a function that is inside the controller. To test, I went to `http://local.store.com/app_dev.php/` and `http://local.store.com/` but I do not see a 500 error page.

Comment: When I place the `$response` code inside a function that is inside the controller, and test via `http://local.store.com/app_dev.php/bad-url` I get a Google Chrome 500 page instead of my Symfony 500 error page.

Answer (score 33):

You can do:

```
throw new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(500, "Some description");
```

Comment: Upvoting because using `HttpException` makes it more obvious from the code that the developer intended to directly cause a 500 response.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to:

`return new Response('', 500);`

Don't forget to include `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to do it can be:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

throw new HttpException(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'Testing the 500 error');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/HttpException.html).

Another way should be doing something like `1/0;`, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a `FatalErrorException` in Symfony2 to see if you app is handling it correctly, you can create an action like this in your controller:

```
public function fatalErrorExceptionAction()
{
    $unknown->getVoid();
}
```

The division by zero will generate a `Warning` while throwing the `Exception`, well, it'll just throw it. :-)